# Php, lock database while request?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

This question might be too broad though. So websites uses common database, what if at line 2:

```
\Doctrine\Repository::getUser()->findById(1)
```

is OK, but this user might be deleted. So 6 rows later, at line 8:

```
\Doctrine\Repository::getUser()->findById(1)
```

will throw an exception! A general solution would be prevent DELETE / UPDATE commands while a request is in progress. But how to?

Comment: Another solution is handling the exceptions.

Comment: or `SELECT FOR UPDATE ` and stuff

Comment: have a look at locking: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html

Answer (score 2):

That is what transactions are for. See http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#approach-2-explicitly

Modified example for your case:

```
$em->getConnection()->beginTransaction(); // suspend auto-commit
try {
    \Doctrine\Repository::getUser()->findById(1)
    //... do some work
    \Doctrine\Repository::getUser()->findById(1)
    // you're done with that particular user
    $em->getConnection()->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $em->getConnection()->rollBack();
    throw $e;
}
```

Be careful that your repository is using right instance of EntityManager(`$em`)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it is bad practise to fully delete any data from the database. Seeing as big data for companies is a big thing a the momnent. So I recommend using a boolean to "delete" stuff so you can always go back and look at users and other things. But if you do really want to delete users handle the exception

Should go something like

```
if(getUser->findById(1)){
   getUser->findById(1);
}else{
   return "some error message" ; 
}
```

Comment: soft delete are also a bad practice, IMHO.

Comment: True, I am used to doing this as the company I work at wants it done that way, not saying it is ideal just an option.